# jQuery innerHeight() returning wrong value

Tags: jquery

I'm using [CSS Tricks Smooth Scrolling](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/) to make my menu links scroll to different parts of a page. I added `- jQuery('#masthead').height()` to account for the height of the fixed navigation bar. However, when I click a menu item and the page scrolls to that point, there appears to be one extra pixel between the menu bar and the location it's scrolling to. [See what I mean here](http://rileydemocracy.com).

Here's my jQuery code:

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = jQuery(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : jQuery('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        jQuery('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top - jQuery('#masthead').innerHeight()
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Working fine to me...

Answer (score 0):

the funtion `innerHeight()` will not add padding or border, you should use `outerHeight()` instead and then will work as expected.

the jQuery code should be:

```
    jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = jQuery(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : jQuery('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        jQuery('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top - jQuery('#masthead'). outerHeight()
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it has the exact same problem, even when I use outerHeight()! :(

Comment: "About HELPS" and "Contact". They both scroll down to 1px above where I want. For example, if you click "Contact" it scrolls down to contact and you can see a 1px white line below the menu from the above "About HELPS" section.

Comment: i can see the mistake only at contact, and when i check the code, i see you have #contact { padding :1px; } , why that padding added there ?

Comment: I had to add that to make #contact take up the whole space. Without it, it fits to the content and the scrolling effect is even more off (uncheck the padding: 1px in Dev Tools and try clicking around in the menu to see what I mean). I don't think it's causing the issue because { box-sizing: border-box } is applied. What do you think?